# AngularJS ng-click change color on two tds within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have some code that lists out items in a table from a database. The click function toggles the cells between green and red.

```
<tr ng-repeat="team in Pool">
     <td ng-class="{'btn-danger': namestarted[$index], 'btn-success': !namestarted[$index]}" ng-click="changeColor(team.chrTeamName, $index)">{{ team.chrTeamName }}</td>
     <td>{{ team.intSeed }}</td>
     <td ng-class="{'btn-danger': divstarted[$index], 'btn-success': !divstarted[$index]}" ng-click="changeColor(team.chrDivision, $index)">{{ team.chrDivision }}</td>
</tr>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.namestarted = [];
$scope.divstarted = [];
$scope.changeColor= function (status, index) {
  if(status == "Name"){
     //How to know if the 'Name" is Selected or NotSelected???
     $scope.namestarted [index] = !$scope.namestarted [index];}
  else
     $scope.divstarted [index] = !$scope.divstarted [index];
}
```

Now When i click "Name" or "Division", i need to know whether it is Selected or NotSelected (active or not)??

Comment: your assigning a variable here `if(status = "Name")` instead of doing the actual check `if(status == "Name")`  note the double equals `==`

Comment: Also, you are using the same `started` variable fro both Name and Division, and also the same `$index` variable, since you are using the same repeat on them.